# PHP / MYSQL Select From Where Column Equals ( Advanced )

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I'm not sure how to word this in my title so I'll try and explain the best I can here.

I want to create a news page for my website, having around 8 articles per page, which would be one update via SQL. But I wondered if there was a way to select a particular article based on it's theme using PHP later on. What I would have are 2 tables:

```
Articles:    ID | Article 1 | Article 2 | Article 3 | etc
Themes:      ID | Theme 1 | Theme 2 | Theme 3 | etc
```

So a basic post would look like:

```
Articles:     1 | Text for article 1 | Text for article 2 | Text for article 3 | etc
Articles:     2 | Text for article 1 | Text for article 2 | Text for article 3 | etc
Themes:       1 | Local | Sport | Business | etc
Themes:       2 | Business | Sport | Local | etc
```

So here, In **Post 1**, `Article 1` is a post about the local area and `Article 2` is about Sport, whereas in **Post 2**, `Article 1` is about the Business and `Article 2` is about Sport.

What I would like to do is have a PHP script which can select any article from any column based on it's theme.

So for instance:

```
SELECT ( CELL ) FROM articles WHERE ( THE CORESPONDING COLUMN IN THEMES ) = 'Business'
```

I'd also like to be able to select multiple rows. (`SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 12`).

Can anyone advise or help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join)

Comment: Which Join would I use to achieve what I'm trying to do?