# INNER JOIN on a table witch do not have any data

Tags: join, inner-join

I'm trying to use the `INNER JOIN` functionality in my phpMyAdmin.

My query looks like this:
`SELECT * FROM ___Bookings INNER JOIN ___Origins ON ___Bookings.BOO_Origin=___Origins.ORI_Id WHERE BOO_Id=1`.

The problem is at this step nothing is populated into the `___Origins` table. So my query returns `0 row`.

How to change my query to return a row even if I do not have the joined table populated ?

Also what's the difference between `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are the same in mysql. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join . You want a `LEFT JOIN` in your case.

Comment: `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are the same.  You can try `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`, depending on which table you want to show whether the other table has records or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to join the tables based on the data in the `__BOOKINGS` table. That's a job for `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER JOIN` (which is the same as `JOIN`).

Refer here for more information on SQL Joins: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference between Join and Inner Join (you can search for it also if this isn't enough).

For the other part - how can it return a row when there isn't one? 
If you need a response from PHP you can set something like

```
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo $records;
}
else {echo "N";}
```

And in you other code just state if the response is "N" (or something else) do something or not do anything.