# TypeORM subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

Based on typeORM [docs](http://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-subqueries) on using subqueries, there are explained how to create subqueries.
Example:

```
const qb = await getRepository(Post).createQueryBuilder("post");
const posts = qb
    .where("post.title IN " + qb.subQuery().select("user.name").from(User, "user").where("user.registered = :registered").getQuery())
    .setParameter("registered", true)
    .getMany();
```

But there is no equivalent as to what the SQL would be.

Supposed that I have the query which contains subqueries like the following:

```
SELECT a, TO_CHAR (MAX (jointable.f), 'MON YYYY') as f,
   t3.c, t3.d, t1.e
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.e = t1.e
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.d = t2.d
JOIN
 (SELECT f, t4.g, t5.e, t6.h
   FROM table4 t4 
   JOIN table5 t5 ON t4.g = t5.g
   JOIN table6 t6 ON t6.g = t4.g
   AND (t6.i = 2
        OR (t6.i = 1 AND j = 1)
       )
     WHERE t4.k = 4
     ) jointable ON t1.e = jointable.e
WHERE jointable.h = :h
AND(:d = 3 OR 
    t3."d" = :d
   )
GROUP BY a, t3.c, t3.d, t1.e
ORDER BY a ASC
```

How should I use the typeORM query builder function for the SQL query above?

Assuming that I had created entities related to all table being used on the query above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I hope this answer could help others to use TypeORM subquery.

```
const subquery = await getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(table4, 't4')
    .select('"t4".f')
    .addSelect('"t4".g')
    .addSelect('"t5".e')
    .addSelect('"t6".h')
    .innerJoin(table5, 't5', '"t4".g = "t5".g')
    .innerJoin(table6, 't6', '"t6".g = "t4".g')
    .where('"t4".k = 4 AND ("t6".i = 2 OR ("t6".i = 1 AND "t6".j = 1))');

  model = await getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(table1, 't1')
    .select('"t1".a')
    .addSelect("TO_CHAR (MAX (jointable.f), 'MON YYYY')", 'f')
    .addSelect('"t3".c')
    .addSelect('"t3".d')
    .addSelect('"t1".e')
    .leftJoin('table2', 't2', '"t2".e = "t1".e')
    .innerJoin(table3, 't3', '"t3".d = "t2".d')
    .innerJoin('('+subquery.getQuery()+')', 'jointable', '"t1".e = jointable.e')
    .where('jointable.h = :h AND (:d = 3 OR "t3".d = :d)',
      { h: h, d: d })
    .groupBy('"t1".a, "t3".c, "t3".d, "t1".e')
    .orderBy('"t1".a', 'ASC')
    .getRawMany();
```

I was using `'('+subquery.getQuery()+')'` for getting the subquery select query as an equivalent to

> (SELECT f, t4.g, t5.e, t6.h   ....
>
> ......
>
> ....    ) jointable ON t1.e = jointable.e

Based on what I understand:

- [`Join` actually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join) [is equal to `inner join`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206035/join-vs-inner-join-and-full-outer-join)
- `.select` is and equivalent of `select` in SQL. You could also add
  [`aliases`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#what-are-aliases-for) ([as in SQL](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/alias)).
- `.addSelect` is similar to `, in select`
- [There are two types of results you can get using select query
  builder: entities or raw results](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder). To describe whether you want
  the data as entities (`getOne` and `getMany`) or what it
  is(`getRawOne` and `getRawMany`).