# JOIN SQL is not working when join table is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where multiple table data exists for a user but if empty one table from any of them then SQL return empty data even other tables data exist like below SQL

```
$id = 40;
SELECT * 
  FROM players a
  JOIN pitcher b 
    ON a.id = b.user_id 
  JOIN outfield_position c 
    ON a.id = c.user_id
  JOIN infield_position d
    ON a.id = d.user_id
  JOIN defensive_statistics e
    ON a.id = e.user_id
  JOIN career f
    ON a.id = f.user_id
 WHERE a.id = $id
```

like if `$outfield_position` table is empty then the SQL returns an empty array but sometimes maybe data here, what can I do if data available or not available every way can works?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: That's what `LEFT JOIN` was invented for.

Comment: Yes! it is, thanks so much

Comment: This code looks like it's riddled with [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/) so it's worth using placeholder values whenever possible. Why are the table names dynamic? That's usually a sign of an irregular schema that needs to be expressed in [proper relational database terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Does it really make sense to have so many different tables

Answer (score 0):

The default join used is inner join and as already explained here [joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join) .
The output in this case will be intersection of the tables it is joined with,so if any table does not have any value then intersection will give empty result.

You can try with LEFT OUTER JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN , in Left Outer Join if data is present in `$players` the value will be displayed.If unsure about the data Full Outer join will give all the results from all the tables.