# Only JOIN means what in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, join

I,m trying this query but don't know what kind join is this inner join or anything else?

```
select * 
FROM abc 
  JOIN xyz  on abc.id =xyz_id;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565620/difference-between-join-and-inner-join) - this is standard SQL not RDBMS dependant

Answer (score 2):

This is an `INNER` join.  If you added the `INNER` keyword before `JOIN`, it will do the same thing.  It's an optional keyword.

The following join types are listed in [the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html)

- `[ INNER ] JOIN`
- `LEFT [ OUTER ] JOIN`
- `RIGHT [ OUTER ] JOIN`
- `FULL [ OUTER ] JOIN`
- `CROSS JOIN`

The content in square brackets is optional in the grammar but omitting it still gives the same join type.